# Entity Framework SQLite Error 1: 'no such table: __EFMigrationsHistory' - Database is not created

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework, .net-core

I am trying to follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LrZwd-f0M4I) tutorial

initially **dotnet ef migrations add initialmigration** did not work. (could not find command)

I updated VS2022 to 17.4.4 , and ran **dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef** and then was able to create the initial migration.

I am now getting and error when running **dotnet ef database update**

The error I get is

*PS D:\Soft\Source\ToDoApi\todoapi> dotnet ef database update
Build started...
Build succeeded.
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
Executed DbCommand (9ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "sqlite_master" WHERE "name" = '__EFMigrationsHistory' AND "type" = 'table';
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
CREATE TABLE "__EFMigrationsHistory" (
"MigrationId" TEXT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT "PK___EFMigrationsHistory" PRIMARY KEY,
"ProductVersion" TEXT NOT NULL
);
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "sqlite_master" WHERE "name" = '__EFMigrationsHistory' AND "type" = 'table';
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations[20402]
Applying migration '20230117171527_InitialMigration'.
Applying migration '20230117171527_InitialMigration'.
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
CREATE TABLE "ToDos" (
"Id" INTEGER NOT NULL CONSTRAINT "PK_ToDos" PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
"ToDoName" TEXT NULL
);
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
Failed executing DbCommand (2ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
INSERT INTO "__EFMigrationsHistory" ("MigrationId", "ProductVersion")
VALUES ('20230117171527_InitialMigration', '7.0.2');
**Failed executing DbCommand (2ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
INSERT INTO "__EFMigrationsHistory" ("MigrationId", "ProductVersion")
VALUES ('20230117171527_InitialMigration', '7.0.2');
Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException (0x80004005): SQLite Error 1: 'no such table: __EFMigrationsHistory'.***

I do not see a sqlite database file, or reference to it in the solution explorer although it seemed to have done a **select count(*) from sqlite_master** table without failing?

It looks like the database was not created

I looked at [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73508902/entity-framework-sqlite-error-1-no-such-table-efmigrationshistory) which gives the same error due to not finding the path to the DB - not sure if this could also be my problem - but how to resolve it?

I have tried removing the migration: **dotnet ef migrations remove** and adding it again but I still get the same error when I run  **dotnet ef database update**

I tried updating the dotnet tool **dotnet ef update --global dotnet-ef** (Tool 'dotnet-ef' was reinstalled with the latest stable version (version '7.0.2').)

I have these nuget packages installed:

a) Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design 7.0.2

b) Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite 7.0.2

Any ideas?

**Edit**

@art Here are the appsettings.json

```
   {
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    },
    "ConnectionStrings": {
      "SqliteConnection": "Data Source=Todo.db"
    }
  }
}
```

and program.cs

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using ToDoAPI.Data;
using ToDoAPI.Models;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(opt =>
    opt.UseSqlite(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("SqliteConnection")));

var app = builder.Build();


app.Run();
```

and AppDbContext

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using ToDoAPI.Models;

namespace ToDoAPI.Data
{
    public class AppDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<ToDo> ToDos => Set<ToDo>();
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like there is small misspelling error. Can you provide code of Program.cs and content of your appsettings.json or appsettings.Development.json where you placed connection string.

Comment: @ArtursMednis thanks for your reply - I have edited the question with requested info

Comment: @RitchieB were you able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your appsettings.json hierarchy "ConnectionStrings" is under "Logging"

```
{
    "Logging": {
        ... ,
        "ConnectionStrings": { ... }
    }
}
```

Thats why program can't find path to DB

"ConnectionStrings" should be next to "Logging"

```
{
    "Logging": { ... },
    "ConnectionStrings": { ... }
}
```

Comment: this did not work, the issue is different. It is not able to find the table.

Comment: @coderkemp It definitely worked for the circumstances described in the question.
I tried it myself. If you follow the same tutorial but misplace ConnectionStrings then you get the same error as in question.

Comment: @coderkemp If you follow the same tutorial, get same error, but your config is correct, then I'm sure you have small misspelling somewhere else.

Comment: agree that the above could also be one of the fixes for the developers facing similar errors. I have described here in detail: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77025767/6939269 other possible solution if that could help someone

Comment: @coderkemp Your link is off topic. This question is totally different from the link.

Comment: it's easy to get confused with the bracket closings in app settings. I got this issue and fixed (already knew the solution, but adding my thoughts here as the question is posted). one trick is to open/collapse sections to make sure the connection string is in the proper bracket section. another is to simply debug Program.cs, and manually collect the connection string and make sure it is not null.